# How to open multiple NetCDF files with xarray via OpenDAP?

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, opendap

I'm trying to open multiple NetCDF files hosted on OpenDAP on a THREDDS server, using `xarray.open_mfdataset()`, but I get an error. If I open only one file (but still with `open_mfdataset()`), it works, if I open two, it doesn't.

For example, this works just fine:

```
import xarray as xr
chunks = {'time' : 1, 'depth' : 1}
paths  = [
    'http://thredds.met.no/thredds/dodsC/fou-hi/norkyst800m-1h/NorKyst-800m_ZDEPTHS_his.an.2017022000.nc',
    ]
d = xr.open_mfdataset(paths, chunks = chunks)
```

while this doesn't:

```
import xarray as xr
chunks = {'time' : 1, 'depth' : 1}
paths  = [
    'http://thredds.met.no/thredds/dodsC/fou-hi/norkyst800m-1h/NorKyst-800m_ZDEPTHS_his.an.2017022000.nc',
    'http://thredds.met.no/thredds/dodsC/fou-hi/norkyst800m-1h/NorKyst-800m_ZDEPTHS_his.an.2017022100.nc',
    ]
d = xr.open_mfdataset(paths, chunks = chunks)
```

I'm running this in a jupyter notebook, and I don't get any output in the notebook, it just keeps running, while in the terminal it prints the following

```
CURL Error: Failed initialization
curl error details:
CURL Error: Failed initialization
CURL Error: Failed initialization
CURL Error: Failed initialization
syntax error, unexpected WORD_WORD, expecting SCAN_ATTR or SCAN_DATASET or SCAN_ERROR
context: !�zF^@L������@L�Ы�J�@L�y@L�G`Lp@L�X�ڭ@L�/��a@L���@L��{�:@@L�Hl�D@L���i@L�f���@L�>����@L�x��f@L��DA�h@L�����@L��ڭ�M@L�u���@M
CURL Error: Failed initialization
curl error details:
CURL Error: Failed initialization
CURL Error: Failed initialization
syntax error, unexpected WORD_WORD, expecting $end
context: Dataset { Structure { Float64 lon[Y = 902][X = 2602]; } lon;} fou-hi/norkyst800m-1h/NorKyst-800m_ZDEPTHS_his.an.2017022100.nc;Data^:
CURL Error: Failed initialization
CURL Error: Failed initialization
CURL Error: Failed initialization
syntax error, unexpected WORD_WORD, expecting SCAN_ATTR or SCAN_DATASET or SCAN_ERROR
context: �@��&��D^@�h�N�{@��I$�@B�
```

and from there on, it just degenerates into printing more garbage.

Isn't this supposed to work just fine?

Edit:

I wasn't aware of this before, but it turns out the netCDF4 library also supports opening multiple paths as one dataset. I'm not sure if this is relevant, as I don't know if xarray and netCDF4 use the same backends, but in any case, the following works just fine. At least that suggests the problem isn't at the server side.

```
import netCDF4 as nc
d = nc.MFDataset([
    'http://thredds.met.no/thredds/dodsC/fou-hi/norkyst800m-1h/NorKyst-800m_ZDEPTHS_his.an.2017022000.nc',
    'http://thredds.met.no/thredds/dodsC/fou-hi/norkyst800m-1h/NorKyst-800m_ZDEPTHS_his.an.2017022100.nc',
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug of some sort to me -- you are using the API properly and there is no inherent reason why this shouldn't work. But I don't know which system is at fault -- most likely it's either the netCDF-C OpenDAP reader or the remote OpenDAP server.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this before posting, but I just discovered that the netCDF4 library for python has a function called `MFDataset()`. Opening the same two paths with that works just fine (I'll edit my question to include this information).

Comment: It's hard to have a dialog to debug something on StackOverflow. Can you please open an issue on the xarray github page instead?

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks.